# Seeking to Start Time in Piped FFMPEG Input

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to convert a series of videos into a livestream with FFMPEG. To do this, I have a program which copies video files to stdout and have configured ffmpeg to read from a pipe input.

The only issue is I cannot seek to a particular start time with `-ss`. I can specify duration with `-t`, but the output will always begin at the start of the input stream. For example:

```
cat input.ts | \
ffmpeg -ss 00:01:15 \
    -t 30 \
    -i pipe: \
    -c:v copy \
    -c:a copy \
    output.ts
```

FFMPEG reports `pipe:: could not seek to position XXXX.XX` and begins from the start of the stream, but I am wondering if there is some other way to accomplish this without trimming the files before piping.

Comment: Place `-ss` and `-t` after the input. You may have to adjust `-ss` value to get closer to desired inpoint.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't try that. It works, thank you!